# how to post and update careers option after placed in play store

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have developed some company website in that i had careers option.now using text view i am displaying job openings,but when they update in website app also should get update and if they want to post in app only means how i update or post job opening after placing in google play store.
please explain with code.

```
     WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv);

    webView.loadData("yourCode Html to load on the webView " , "text/html" ,"utf-8");

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.emergtechinc.com/Careers/careers-cjo.aspx");


       I USED WEBVIEW AND DISPLAYED THE CURRENOPENINGS PAGE.IS IT RIGHT BUT I GOT WHOLE WEBSITE PAGE.HOW CAN I DISPLAY WHATEVER I NEED FROM WEBSITE.PLEASE HELP ME.
```

Comment: how are you communicating with the server or backend or your source? or you manually write it in the app?

Comment: Your code has no relevance to the question you are asking.

Comment: i dont know how to communicate now  i am displaying in text view.please say me how to code for that.whatever job postings are displayed in website i should display in app

Comment: CAN U HELP ME  –  Elltz